# export csv from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport, database, nosql

I am new to MongoDB. I want to export some fields to csv file and if that field is present in particular row then I want empty value in that field. Currently I am trying this:

```
mongoexport --host hostname --collection collectionname -q '{}' -f "field1","field2" --db dbname --username user --password pass --out out.csv
```

But problem is that output does not keep the field if field value is not present in the database. Any suggestion how can I perform the desired operation?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mongoexport --host hostname --username user --password pass --db dbname --collection collectionname --type=csv --fields field1,field2 --query '{field1: { $exists: true}, field2: { $exists: true}}' --out out.csv
```

For more detail: [Click here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

Comment: Thank you @Indrajeet , But I think this will only return the document where both field1 and fireld2 are present but what I am asking is even only one of the field exists then query should return that document with empty in the field which does not exists.